# TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord

Trying to make a very basic chatbot for discord.

Now, I know why my codes have an error and that there is another question that is almost identical to mine. However I tried the solution for the other one and sadly it didn't work in my case. So anyone knows how should I fix this function?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
r1 = ['Hello!', 'Hi!', 'Greetings!']
r2 = ['I am feeling excellent!' 'Working today feels great!']
if client.user.id != message.author.id:
    if client.user.mentioned_in(message) and message.mention_everyone is False:
        if 'help' in message.content.lower():
            await message.channel.send(
            'How may I assist you?')
        else:
            await message.add_reaction('')  # :eyes:
    if ['hi', 'hello'] in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send(f'{random.choice(r1)}')
```

This will give me the type error because I have a list before message.content.lower()

---

```
    if message.content.lower() in ['How are you?', 'How are you doing?', 'How are you feeling?']:
        await message.channel.send(f'{random.choice(r2)}')
```

---

While this will just make the bot unresponsive(not expecting it to work, but tried anyways), does not even report any error in console.

Again, I am feeling that I missed something really obvious but I just couldn't figure it out. Any help is appreciated. Also, I know that I can break the list apart and do each word individually, but that will make it unnecessarily messy.

Comment: Do you mean `if any(i in message.content.lower().split() for i in ['hi', 'hello'])`?

Comment: Ah yes, that solves the issue perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

can be solved with if any(i in message.content.lower().split() for i in ['hi', 'hello']) 
Thanks for your help!